# Is there any threat to web scrape a site that only supports SSL 3 / TLS 1.0?

Tags: ssl, web-scraping

I was tasked with writing a web scraper to pull data from a website that only supports SSL 3 / TLS 1.0 (as of 28 Dec 2019). Is there any threat on my side? Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, because you are executing code you would not otherwise execute, you are increasing your attack surface.

Having said that, if you are merely saving the site's contents as files, the type of encryption of lack of same does not expose you to any known vulnerability. The known problems with SSLv3 have to do with an adversary's ability to decrypt a supposedly secure connection; but if you are not sending any secrets (beyond the per-session credentials) there are no secrets being leaked.

Having said that, again theoretically speaking, a large number of leaked sessions could give an attacker insights into whether you are using a particular insufficiently random method to generate temporary secrets, or other similar intelligence.

Still here some suggestive notes for additional threat modeling.

- We assume the scraping event does not need to remain undetected and undisclosed. Still then, does the remote site receive enough regular traffic that a scraper will not stick out like a sore thumb?
- We assume that the remote site is friendly or neutral. If it is operated by a competitor or adversary, the issues with this particular SSL version will be a minor detail, but possibly exacerbate other problems.
- We assume that scraping the entire site will not require thousands of visits or more.

Comment: Really interesting notes! I've only recently started studying cryptography/encryption more thoroughly, so my bad if that was too novice. I'd like to dig deeper on those points you surfaced. Recommend any reading?

Comment: Not sure what to recommend but [security.se] should have pointers.